# Steady-state is undetermined in 3 differential equations system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of 3 differential equations as:

$\dot{x}=(x+2)\dot{y}+\dot{z}$
  $\dot{y}=y-3$
  $\dot{z}=3x+z-5$

I am trying to conduct a stability analysis around the steady-state. But as you can see, while steady-state value of `y` and `z` can be determined from `\dot{y}=0` and `\dot{z}=0`, the steady-state value of `x` cannot.

In this case, can any value of `x` can be a steady-state and used in the stability analysis? Or the steady-state is undetermined in this system and so I cannot conduct the stability analysis?

Comment: The steady state for this equation holds at $(x,0,0)$ for any value of $x$.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: @Semsem I have slightly changed the equations. Can you please see once more if the steady state for this equation can be said to holds at `(x,3,5-3x)` for any value of `x`?

Comment: If you want to see it more clearly you can substitute $\dot{y}=\ldots,\dot{z}=\ldots$ into the equation for $\dot{x}$ to find: $\dot{x} = xy + 2y + z - 11 = (z - (5-3x)) - (2+x)(y-3)$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks, but it gives a repetition of \dot{z}. Does this system have the steady-state?

Comment: Yes $(x,3,5-3x)$ for any $x$. The main point to take from this problem: if the equation-system does not determine one of the variables (here $x$) then this variables is a free variable.

Comment: @Winther Then in this case, can I say `(x,3,5-3x)` for each `x` is a unique equilibrium of this system? This is important since I am conducting the local stability analysis around an isolated equilibrium.

Comment: It certainly is a equilibrium, but I would not use the word unique. Its better to say the all equilibrium points are on the form $(x,3,5-3x)$ for some $x$. When you do the stability analysis you will find that for some $x$ the eq. is unstable and for some $x$ it will be stable.

Comment: btw when you do the stability analysis it should be enough to note that if you perturb around $y = 3$ then the solution reads $y = 3 + \delta e^t$ so all equilibriums are unstable.

Comment: @Winther Great! Thank you so much. One last question: Would limit cycle (Hopf bifurcation) possibly emerge in the system with one free variable like my example here?

Comment: I don't think so. Linearizing about a equilibrium point we get $\dot{\vec{\delta X}} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}3 & 2 & 1 \\0 & 1 & 0\\3 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)\vec{\delta X}$ and the matrix has only real eigenvalues.

Comment: As for the system I provided here, yes, you are right. But in general, for the system with one free variable, would it be possible to have limit cycle? My question is whether the existence of one free variable excludes the possibility of limit cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Your system is given as

$$\dot{x}=(x+2)\dot{y}+\dot{z}=(x+2)(y-3)+3x+z-5$$
$$\dot{y}=y-3$$
$$\dot{z}=3x+z-5$$

In order to determine the equilibrium points, we set $\dot{x}=\dot{y}=\dot{z}=0$ such that we obtain

$$\dot{x}=0=(x+2)\cdot 0+0$$
$$\dot{y}=0=y_\text{eq}-3$$
$$\dot{z}=0=3x_\text{eq}+z_\text{eq}-5$$

So we obtain for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

$$x_\text{eq} = \alpha$$
$$y_\text{eq} = 3$$
$$z_\text{eq} = 5-3\alpha$$

as equilibrium points. Now, you can go ahead and investigate this continuous set of equilibrium points note that these equilibria cannot be asymptotically stable because you can choose infinitesimally close initials conditions next to an equilibrium point which is also an equilibrium point and hence will not be attracted to the equilibrium point that you are investigating. By looking at the second equation you can already see that all these equilibria should be unstable because $\dot{y} = y -3$ is unstable.